# Unable to complete saved object migrations for the [.kibana_task_manager] index. Please check the health of your Elasticsearch cluster and try again

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, restore

I accidentally closed some indices in order to proceed from Snapshot, but for some reason the KIBANA is suddenly not accessible after I closed the .kibana_security_session. I tried to restart the Kibana and get this error:

---

FATAL  Error: Unable to complete saved object migrations for the [.kibana_task_manager] index. Please check the health of your Elasticsearch cluster and try again. Unexpected Elasticsearch ResponseError: statusCode: 400, method: GET, url: /_tasks/lknaevIIRmqBEWw_qYgDyg%3A24796349?wait_for_completion=true&timeout=60s error: [index_closed_exception]: closed,

Comment: Solved by re-opening indices using the command curl -u "credential" -XPOST http://localhost:9200/_all/_open